# CentOS 6.4 Mail Server

Tags: centos, configuration, postfix

I'm trying to install a mail server on my root server.

There are many many how to's on the internet I tried to get my own mail server with IMAP/SMTP. Also maybe some virus/spam detection.

I've got a Root Server (CentOS 6.4) and a own domain (let us say 'morekings.com').

I want to have some email adresses (admin@morekings.com, peter@morekings.com, etc).
Nice would be some kind of encryption (ssl/tsl). But I have no official cert.

Roughly speaking I removed sendmail, installed postfix and cyrus and configured it.
Among others for example I tried this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-postfix-on-centos-6

In main.cf of Postfix I used this:

```
myhostname              = mail.morekings.com 
mydomain                = morekings.com
```

Is this right?

At least I got it to send mails via Thunderbird and send/receive via telnet.

Comment: I put this tutorial together a while ago for setting up a mail server on CentOS 5 which might be helpful for you: http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/226/how-to-setup-a-mail-server-on-centos-5/. I use sendmail in the tutorial, not postfix but it still might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

**myhostname**: is the host name of the system (i.e, the system is called mail or mail.example.com). You can find it in `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/hostname`

**mydomain**: is the domain name for the email server (it can be a real or fake domain name). So when you add a mail user *foo* for your configuration his mail will be `foo@morekings.com`. If you set it like `mydomain=mail.morekings.com` than it will be *foo@mail.morekings.com`*... If you use`**myorigin = $mydomain**`

This is the default settings on postfix, if you don't specify mydomain.

See [here](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html)

Comment: first line is for IPv4, so consider changing your hostname like, for example, `127.0.0.1 mail.morekings.com mailmorekings localhost.localdomain localhost`, change `HOSTNAME=mail.morekings.com` in `/etc/sysconfig/network` and do `/etc/init.d/network restart` or like in example [here](http://ithelpblog.com/os/linux/redhat/centos-redhat/howto-change-hostname-without-reboot-on-centos-or-redhat-rhel/) . Ofcourse if you have public IP or you will be relaying you mail to some other server, you need to tell your DNS that mail.morekings.com has that IP.

Comment: Sorry that I deleted my comment. I just wanted edit it again but it wasnt possible anymore. I'm really new to this stackexchange network. I know this is a little bit off topic and doesnt treat my question but: Why do I have to change my hosts file? www.morekings.com forwards to my public IP adress already. Is it just for internal behaviors? In my etc/sys/config/network also only is this line: **NETWORKING=yes**. I guess I have to read some more about this. Do you maybe have some helpfull article for me?

Comment: what is the output of `hostname`, if you already registered that `hostname` with your DNS, than in postfix: `myhostname=<output you get from hostname>`, and if it's `morekings.com` than keep `mydomain=morekings.com`. If this isn't mail server only

Comment: `hostname` is `xxxxx.servers.jiffybox.de` which is not my _morekings.com_ but the adress which is given from my root server provider.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ISPmail](https://workaround.org) tutorials, their are made for Debian releases but it's easy to modify them for CentOS. They are not only explaining how to install and configure basic services but how to put them all together in to a professional [mail server](https://workaround.org/ispmail/wheezy/big-picture) with antivirus and spam filters.